# Get a Cast button on YouTube for a custom cast solution

Tags: casting, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Recently I have made a Custom local Flask website to cast from a local device to a RPi4 Connected to my TV. There is a [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bhMP.jpg) and it is also controllable by GET requests, the main way that the casting works, is in fact passing data from js to python via GET Requests.

It is easy to control but still getting to the main question here:
Is it possible to have a cast button on youtube for my solution? To trick youtube into thinking it is a chromecast or any other way? After pressing the cast button on youtube it would in some way go to my solutions address and pass along the Video URL as a GET Request.

Anyone knows is this possible?

Comment: the only way I think this is possible is if you use a Browse extension to modify the youtube page and create this button for you, sending the URL to your local application.

Comment: create a browser extension running a background script gets the URL navigates to your solutions address and passes the video URL using a get URL. It requires just a small script which adds a button to the youtube page and on a press pass the URL to your desired location

Comment: The only problem with browser extensions would be that the solution is mainly used by mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a TV emulator by reprogramming an old smartphone to appear as a tv for network and relay all screen mirroring request data to your server with a get request. That's what I'd do.